# Libgdx - pixmap already disposed

Tags: android, libgdx

```
04-16 12:17:58.353 12029-12056/com.nisvol.squaresmash E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 664
                                                                Process: com.nisvol.squaresmash, PID: 12029
                                                                com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Pixmap already disposed!
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.dispose(Pixmap.java:315)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.PixmapPacker$Page$1.dispose(PixmapPacker.java:379)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont.dispose(BitmapFont.java:315)
                                                                    at com.nisvol.squaresmash.screens.GameScreen.dispose(GameScreen.java:306)
                                                                    at com.nisvol.squaresmash.screens.GameScreen.changeScreen(GameScreen.java:209)
                                                                    at com.nisvol.squaresmash.screens.GameScreen.update(GameScreen.java:168)
                                                                    at com.nisvol.squaresmash.screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:261)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
                                                                    at com.nisvol.squaresmash.SquareSmash.render(SquareSmash.java:44)
                                                                    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onDrawFrame(AndroidGraphics.java:474)
                                                                    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
                                                                    at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
04-16 12:18:02.533 12029-12029/com.nisvol.squaresmash E/AndroidGraphics: waiting for pause synchronization took too long; assuming deadlock and killing
```

I know this might not be enough, just the error I mean. But the thing is that my game runs fine on my phone, but then I tried it on an older phone, and the game kept crashing. But the weird thing is it crashed only when I got a score higher than about 50, and after it went to the game over screen.

So I start the Game Screen and play the game, get a higher score than 50 (objects fall from the sky, you have to collect them, and yes if the object is not on the screen it is removed) and when I come to the Game Over Screen it says: game stopped working... And as you can see it says the Pixmap has been disposed??? I have no idea what that means.

The only thing I dispose of in Game Screen is a FreeTypeFontGenerator that is in no way connected to Game Over screen, because I initialize it like this:

```
FreeTypeFontGenerator generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font.ttf"));
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
parameter.size = 40;
parameter.color = Color.BLACK;
showScore = generator.generateFont(parameter);
generator.dispose();
```

And in Game Over Screen I do the same again. So what could be the cause?

Comment: From the error it looks as if you are calling dispose a second time. Maybe you have dispose in both the hide and dispose method. I believe that hide is called automatically on screen change, so this could be your issue. Or you maybe dispose of the pixmap directly after using it and then try to dispose of it again in the main dispose call. Just do a search of the class for any times dispose is called and see if you can find a duplicate. If this isn't the issue, I think we'll need more info

Comment: That is the weird part, I never get the error on my computer or my lg g1... But on my samsung, only if I get to a certain "score" the error pops. And I only dispose in the dispose method. Well nothing makes sense to me. Why would it show an error only if a criteria has been met but also depend on a phone!?

Comment: It must be that is using too much memory and possibly disposes of it automatically (although I thought libgdx didn't do this). This may only happen on an old phone as it has less ram than pc. Check for obvious stuff such as creating new objects in render method etc. If its not this, I'm afraid it's difficult to know the problem

Comment: Well I am using System.gc() in main menu, because yeah I am creating objects in every state. And in the game screen I am creating new objects and removing them after they are out of screen and I am not pooling because I don't think such a tiny game should be causing this. But why would it go and dispose, RANDOMLY? Any ideas?

Comment: @JanLovšin ___Never___ call System.gc() unless it is 110% necessary.